# Setar o componente/app Angular 2 na tag <body>

Tags: html5, angular, angularjs-directives

Gostaria de definir a tag `<body>` como raiz de minha aplicação Angular 2 em vez de crir uma tag filha `<my-app>` (por exemplo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defina `body` como o seletor do componente raiz da sua aplicação.

Algo como

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'body',
    template: '<h1>{{mensagem}}</h1>'
})
export class AppComponent { 
    String mensagem = "Minha primeira aplicação Angular 2";
}
```

Comment: Minha dúvida é justamente esta. Na versão anterior, AngularJS, isso era bem intuitivo pois usávamos uma diretiva como um atributo da tag ex: `<body ng-app="my-app">...</ body>`.
Já no Angular 2, pelo que vi até agora a aplicação ou componente é a própria tag como exemplifiquei antes: `<my-app>...</ my-app>`

Comment: A não ser que você esteja querendo ganhar prêmio por minimalismo, você poderia explicar melhor a solução que você está dando? Obrigado! :)

Comment: @EdgarDamasceno editei a resposta

Comment: Muito bom, @mercador ! Era exatamente o que eu procurava porém não havia atentado para a definição do componente.